# Check if text input contains a specific string

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery snippet to append ' UK' to a text input when the user presses enter on his/her keyboard:

```
jQuery('#myinput').one('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    jQuery('#myinput').val($('#myinput').val() + ' UK');
    return false;
  }
});
```

However, I only want 'UK' to be appended if the text doesn't already contain 'UK'. Is there any easy way to check if 'UK' is already present using jQuery?

I have tried the following, but this appends nothing either way:

```
if ( !'#myinput:contains("UK")') {
   jQuery('#myinput').one('keypress', function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
         jQuery('#myinput').val($('#myinput').val() + ' UK');
         return false;
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if (e.which == 13 && this.value.indexOf('UK') === -1){
```

---

[this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

---

```
if (e.which == 13 && this.value.indexOf('UK') === -1) {
    this.value = this.value + 'UK';
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This works very nicely! Can I also check if it is lowercase 'uk' somehow as well?

Comment: @user1444027 Yes `if (e.which == 13 && (this.value.indexOf('UK') === -1 || this.value.indexOf('Uk'))) {`

Comment: `this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf('uk')`

Comment: @user1444027 or better just check  `if (e.which == 13 && this.value.toUpperCase().indexOf('UK') === -1)`

Comment: @BlackSheep  thanks i was on it too u beat my fingers :)